# $f \colon \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $f$ is continuous , and $f(x+1)+f(x)=x^2$

Tags: continuity, functional-equations

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem:

> Find $f(x)$ ($f(x)$ is not Polynomial function), given that:
>
> $f \colon \mathbb{R} \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}$, $f$ is continuous, and $f(x+1)+f(x)=x^2$

I tried  but couldn't get it that way.

Comment: Notice that the sum of two consecutive triangular numbers sums in a square number so if you define a function that for any $x$ gives you the xth triangular number you're done!

Comment: @RenatoFaraone not quite "done"; the problem specifically asks for a non-polynomial solution.  Also, note that $f$ should be defined over $\Bbb R$, whereas "triangular numbers" are usually integers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It might be helpful to first find $f:\Bbb N \to \Bbb R$, then extend the result.

We can solve the recurrence relation $f(n) + f(n+1) = n^2$ via generating functions: define $F(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty f(n) x^n$.  Then
$$
f(n) + f(n+1) = n^2\\
\sum_{n=0}^\infty [f(n) + f(n+1)]x^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty n^2 x^n \\
\sum_{n=0}^\infty f(n)x^n +
\sum_{n=0}^\infty f(n+1)x^n = 
\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^2 x^n\\ 
\sum_{n=0}^\infty f(n)x^n +
\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)x^{n-1} = 
\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^2 x^n\\ 
F(x) + 
\frac 1x \left(F(x) - f(0)\right) = 
\frac{x(x+1)}{(x-1)^3}\\
xF(x) + 
F(x) - f(0) = 
\frac{x^2(x+1)}{(x-1)^3}\\
(x+1)F(x) = 
\frac{x^2(x+1)}{(x-1)^3} + f(0)\\
F(x) = 
\frac{x^2}{(x-1)^3} + \frac{f(0)}{x+1}\\
\sum_{n=0}^\infty f(n) x^n = 
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n(n+1)}{2} x^n + 
f(0)\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n x^n
$$
So setting $f(0) = a$ for any $a$, we find
$$
f(n) = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} + a(-1)^n = 
\frac{n(n+1)}{2} + a\cos(\pi n)
$$
if a solution to the problem over $\Bbb R$ exists, it must be an extension of this function for some value of $a$.

In fact, $f(x) = \frac{x(x+1)}{2} + a\cos(\pi x)$ seems to work for any $a \in \Bbb R$.

---

A more general solution (taken from Salomo's work) is
$$
f(x) = \frac{x(x+1)}{2} + g(x)
$$
where $g(x)$ satisfies $g(x+1) + g(x) = 0$.

Comment: $\mathbb{N}$ is not dense in $\mathbb{R}$. You will have to think about $\mathbb{Q}$, too.

Comment: I never claimed the extension is unique.  However, any solution over $\Bbb R$, restricted to $\Bbb N$, solves the problem over $\Bbb N$.

Comment: The cleverer thing to do would have been to assume a polynomial solution exists and apply some useful perturbation to that, as I assume Salomo did.

Comment: Yes, but this means that your answer does not answer the question. Why is this the accepted answer?

Comment: This answer doesn't *prove* that the candidate $f(x)$ solves the problem (which is a straightforward calculation), but it shows work on how to derive a suitable "guess".

Comment: Ultimately though, I don't know what OP happens to like about my answer.  For all I know he just accepted it because it's longer.

Comment: To be honest, I don't think your answer should be accepted, other than the reasons stated above, it is not need to use recurrence relation to find that polynomial, what I used is coefficient to be determined. Moreover, without further edit, I posted my better answer before you did...

Comment: @Salomo I've edited my answer to give you credit for getting there first.  Anyway, ultimately OP decided that my answer does something that yours didn't.  I would guess that your answer would have been accepted if you explained the method of undetermined coefficients, as you used it.  The thing that OP seems to have primarily struggled with is finding a nonhomogeneous solution.

Comment: Thank you, but if we can have the right way to go, why should we guess?

Comment: My reason for guessing is that I didn't remember the method of undetermined coefficients.  Maybe for more complicated problems, guessing is useful.  Again, I'm sure if you explained the *smarter* (and saner) method, OP would like your answer better.

Comment: Ok, it can be forgiven for forgetting how to use undetermined coefficients...

Answer (score 6):

Let $f(x)=\frac{x^2-x}{2}+\sin(\pi x)$. Then, $f(x+1)+f(x)=\frac{x^2+2x+1-(x+1)}{2}+\sin(\pi x + \pi)+\frac{x^2-x}{2}+\sin(\pi x)=x^2$.

As $\frac{x^2-x}{2}$ can be found easily, $sin(\pi x)$ can be replaced by any other non-polynomial continuous function $g$ with $g(x+1)+g(x)=0$.

Comment: It's worth noting that the solutions $g$ to the homogeneous equation are precisely those formed by extending any continuous $h \colon [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ with $h(1) = -h(0)$ to the real line

Comment: @G.H.Faust: I am not sure. Does continuity of $h$ as a function on $[0,1]$ imply that $h$ is continuous at $1$ when extended to a function on $\mathbb{R}$? I mean, what happens if we approach $1$ from the right? Or $0$ from the left? The interval $[0,1]$ doesn't see that.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg The condition $h(1) = -h(0)$ is what ensures that $h$ extends to a continuous function; $h$ is continuous at $1$ from the right precisely because it's continuous at $0$ from the right, and $h(1+\varepsilon) = -h(\varepsilon)$. Similarly with $0$ from the left.

Comment: I can't know why the OP accepted the answer he did, but this one looks like hokus pokus: how, why, from where or on what insight we do come to *guess* that $\;f(x)\;$ as defined out of the blue in the very first line? Of course, perhaps some periodicity-like argument on the question could hint towards some trigonmetric function like $\;\sin \pi x\;$ , but I can understand the OP being confused about how to approach questions like this one.

Answer (score 2):

Let's first consider the function on $\mathbb{Z}$.
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^k(f(k+1)+f(k))
&=\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k-1}f(k)+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^kf(k)\\
&=(-1)^{n-1}f(n)+f(0)\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
Furthermore,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^kk^2\tag{2}
&=(-1)^{n-1}\frac{n(n-1)}2
\end{align}
$$
Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ yields
$$
f(n)=\frac{n(n-1)}2+(-1)^nf(0)\tag{3}
$$
If we set $f(0)=0$, we get
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #FFC000]{f(x)=\frac{x(x-1)}2}\tag{4}
$$
Checking, we get
$$
f(x+1)+f(x)=x^2\tag{5}
$$
This gives us one solution. Suppose we have two solutions, $f$ and $g$. Then
$$
(f-g)(x+1)+(f-g)(x)=0\tag{6}
$$
That is, $(f-g)(x+1)=-(f-g)(x)$. Thus, the general solution is
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #FFC000]{f(x)=\frac{x(x-1)}2+h(x)}\tag{7}
$$
where $h$ is any continuous function where $h(x+1)=-h(x)$.

An example of such an $h(x)$ would be $a\cos(\pi x)+b\sin(\pi x)$.

Comment: the question specifically asks for a non-polynomial.

Comment: Sorry, I posted before I had finished the general solution.

Comment: No problem; I just thought you missed it

Answer (score 1):

Let $f$ be a solution of the equation $f(x+1)+f(x)=x^2$. Consider $h(x)=f(x) - \frac{x(x-1)}{2}$, i.e. $f(x)=h(x) + \frac{x(x-1)}{2}$. Then the equation simply becomes:
$$h(x+1) + h(x) = 0$$
It is clear that such a function $h$ is completely determined by what it does on $[0,1[$, where $h$ can be defined arbitrarily. Conversely, every $h$ gives a solution $f$. Finally, $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous if and only if $h : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous.

Comment: In line with my comment on Salomo's answer, this answer needs to be modified. You could have $h \colon [0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ continuous everywhere e.g. $h \colon x \mapsto x$, but not have the $f$ that $h$ extends to being continuous: $\lim\limits_{x \to 1} f(x) = 1$, $f(1) = -f(0) = 0$.

Comment: Yes, but I didn't claim this! For me $h$ is defined on all $\mathbb{R}$. I explicitly stated that this function should be continuous at all points of $[0,1[$. This implies that the whole function is continuous. I don't consider the function on $[0,1[$.

Comment: I interpreted the last two sentences of your answer as defining a solution to the homogeneous equation, consistent with what a given $h$ does on $[0,1)$. I see now that this is not what you're doing. Since you're not speaking of constructing a continuous $h$ from values on the unit interval, the meat of my issue is de facto settled. However, I do believe there is still one error: you require continuity of $h$ on $[0,1]$ to get continuity everywhere. Quite conveniently, extending the $h$ I spoke of in my previous comment to satisfy $h(x) + h(x+1) = 0$ will also produce a counterexample here.

Comment: Ok, I've edited it.